# CorePlot Pie Chart: How to hide X and Y axes?

Tags: ios, core-plot, pie-chart

The Following Code For Pie Chart CorePlot in ios:

```
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:hostingView];

    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

    CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
    pieChart.dataSource = self;
    pieChart.pieRadius = 100.0;
    pieChart.identifier = @"PieChart1";
    pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4;
    pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;
    self.pieData=  [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:90.0], 
                    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:20.0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:30.0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:40.0],
                    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:50.0], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:60.0], nil];
    [graph addPlot:pieChart];
    [pieChart release];
```

That's Output not hide x and y axis in the pie Chart....!
I need to hide X and y axis...!
Help Me ....!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is to remove the axes entirely.

```
graph.axisSet = nil;
```

Comment: @EricSkroch  Hi, Could you please have a look at my question? Thank you so much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997224/the-axis-is-drawn-under-the-plot-in-core-plot