# the axis is drawn under the plot in core plot

Tags: plot, core-plot, axis

I have a graph, and I want to add two blue axes to this graph, in addition to x-axis and y-axis. However, these blue axes appear under the plot. Any idea how to bring the blue axes on top of the plot? Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
    blueAxisList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    CPTXYAxis *blueAxis = [blueAxisList objectForKey:name];
    blueAxis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
    blueAxis.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;

    blueAxis.plotSpace = plotSpace;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];

    lineStyle.lineWidth = 3.f;

    blueAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    blueAxis.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
    blueAxis.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
    blueAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

    // Line cap on lhs
    CPTLineCap *lineCap = [CPTLineCap lineCap];
    lineCap.size      = CGSizeMake(8., 60.);
    lineCap.lineStyle = lineStyle;

    lineCap.lineCapType = CPTLineCapTypeRectangle;
    const double axisLength = plotSpace.xRange.lengthDouble;
    blueAxis.visibleAxisRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:plotSpace.xRange.location length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(axisLength)];
    blueAxis.axisLineCapMax = lineCap;

    NSMutableArray *axesList= [graph.axisSet.axes mutableCopy];

    [axesList addObject: blueAxis];
    graph.axisSet.axes = axesList;
```

Comment: If you aren't, try adding the 2 blue axes to the graph AFTER the plot is added to the graph.

Comment: @weezma2004 The plot is continuously updated, hence there is no AFTER. Do you think I can use layers to solve it? I tried to figure it out how, but cannot find any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using axes to draw lines across the plot, use additional plots. You can draw both lines with the same plot if they use the same line style. Add the blue plot to the graph after the green one to have it drawn on top.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. The user should be able to to move the blue lines and it is why I used axis. The green plot is also plotted continuously, (it is a real time signal). Do you still think I can do something? Do you think I can use layers? @EricSkroch

Comment: Plots and axes *are* layers. You can change the order, but not mix the types (all axes will be together and all plots will be together). You can change the position of a plot line easily, too. Just call `-reloadData` on the plot and give it new data points. It only takes two points to draw a line, so the reload operation should be really fast.